# Incorrect command-line perl error value in $?

Tags: linux, perl, return-value

I am using command-line perl to perform a inplace substitution in a file. This is the code: (note the root perm with sudo)

```
sudo perl -i -pe "s/foo/bar/" config.txt
```

If this succeeds, 'echo $?' return 0. Now I make the file un-writable even for root using chattr like this:

```
sudo chattr +i config.txt
```

I run the same perl command and it fails with this error:

> Can't remove config.txt: Operation not permitted, skipping file.

Which is fine. However, 'echo $?' still returns 0 in this case. Why is this so? Shouldn't it return a non-zero value indicating an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Perl does not come back with a non-zero exit status for this condition (`sudo` passes on the exit status of the command it was given), which is a bit vexing. You can work around the problem by recognizing that the line-reading loop is never entered if the file fails to be renamed and handle it with a flag:

```
sudo perl -i -ne 's/foo/bar/; print; $wrk = 1; }{ $wrk or exit 1' config.txt
```

The Eskimo greeting (or butterfly) "operator" `}{` introduces an `END` block, in a way; what comes after it is executed when the loop reading lines from the file has ended. The way it works is described [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod).

The caveat is that this will also report an error if `config.txt` is empty. A shorter if a bit hackier way is to use the special `$.` line counter variable for the same purpose:

```
sudo perl -i -ne 's/foo/bar/; print; }{ $. or exit 1' config.txt
```